# Torus-geometry algebraic equations using NSolve and Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value, approximation

Somehow a set of naive-looking equations cannot be solved by using `NSolve`. *Mathematica* returns a message like this:

> `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>`

Try using `Reduce`, *Mathematica* still cannot return an answer after some lone time, but it prompts a message after aborting the calculation:

> `Still waiting for a safe time to evaluate $Inspector[]`

They are a set of six Cosine/Sine equations with 6 to-be-solved variables. The six equations are named below as `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, `G1`, `G2`, `G3`. And the six variables are angles `a1`, `b1`, `b2`, `c2`, `a3`, `c3`, all are Reals, and all are in the range of 0 to 2 Pi.

Here are the equations and the code:

```
F1[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = -(41/4) + 
   Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - Cos[b2] (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
F2[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
F3[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   3 Sin[b1] - (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) Sin[b2] + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
G1[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] = 
  Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - Cos[a3] (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
G2[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] = (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] - (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) Sin[
     a3] + 1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
G3[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] = 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 3 Sin[b1] + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);

    NSolve[F1[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 && 
  F2[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 && F3[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 &&
   G1[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 && 
  G2[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 && G3[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 &&
   0 <= a1 < 2 Pi && 0 <= b1 < 2 Pi && 0 <= b2 < 2 Pi && 
  0 <= c2 < 2 Pi && 0 <= a3 < 2 Pi && 0 <= c3 < 2 Pi, {a1, b1, b2, c2,
   a3, c3}, Reals]

Reduce[F1[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 && 
  F2[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 && F3[a1, b1, b2, c2] == 0 &&
   G1[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 && 
  G2[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 && G3[a1, b1, a3, c3] == 0 &&
   0 <= a1 < 2 Pi && 0 <= b1 < 2 Pi && 0 <= b2 < 2 Pi && 
  0 <= c2 < 2 Pi && 0 <= a3 < 2 Pi && 0 <= c3 < 2 Pi, {a1, b1, b2, c2,
   a3, c3}, Reals]
```

**My challenge: Is there any resolution why this set of equations cannot be evaluated/solved numerically by `NSolve`? And the `Reduce`? How can the equations be solved numerically?**

For approximation, it is totally fine to have only about a 5 digit precision. The numerical solution needs not be very precise or exact.

Comment: A hint: try using the Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: Is there a built-in Weierstrass substitution (Tangent half-angle substitution), or should this just be substituted manually?

Comment: I show one approach below. As for the challenge as stated, I will observe that it borders on obvious. The system is far from trivial algebraically, and were it but somewhat more complicated (being intentionally vague there), I would expect the minute or so of computational time could become an hour or a day or more. Conciseness of formulation does not equate to ease of solving.

Comment: New Update: There seem to have bugs in the two answers below. Both cases the Math Kernal closes and jump out of the session.

Comment: New Update: we may get the code working if we try to modify the method via Method->"EndomorphismMatrix" in NSolve.

Answer (score 6):

This should get you started. First the basic definitions to keep this self contained.

```
F1[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = -(41/4) + Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - 
   Cos[b2] (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
F2[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
F3[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] = 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   3 Sin[b1] - (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) Sin[b2] + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);
G1[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] = 
  Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - Cos[a3] (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
G2[a1_, b1_, a3_, 
   c3_] = (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] - (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) Sin[
     a3] + 1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
G3[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] = 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 3 Sin[b1] + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 
132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
```

I convert from trigonometric to ordinary polynomials in the "sin,cos" variables. Also add the usual trig identities.

```
tpolys = TrigExpand[{F1[a1, b1, b2, c2], F2[a1, b1, b2, c2], 
    F3[a1, b1, b2, c2], G1[a1, b1, a3, c3], G2[a1, b1, a3, c3], 
    G3[a1, b1, a3, c3]}];

subs = {Cos[a_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["c", ToString[a]]], 
   Sin[a_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["s", ToString[a]]]};

polys = Numerator[Together[tpolys /. subs]];
vars = Variables[polys];
cvars = Cases[vars, ca_ /; StringMatchQ[ToString[ca], "c" ~~ __]];
svars = Map[ToExpression[StringReplacePart[ToString[#], "s", 1]] &, 
   cvars];
extrapolys = cvars^2 + svars^2 - 1;

system = Join[polys, extrapolys]

(*Out[457]= {-123 + 120 ca1 + 36 ca1 cb1 - 48 cb2 - 42 cb2 cc2 - 
  40 sa1 - 12 cb1 sa1 - 12 sb1 + 16 sb2 + 14 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 41 - 40 ca1 - 12 ca1 cb1 + 16 cb2 + 14 cb2 cc2 + 120 sa1 + 
  36 cb1 sa1 - 12 sb1 + 16 sb2 + 14 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 41 - 40 ca1 - 12 ca1 cb1 + 16 cb2 + 14 cb2 cc2 - 40 sa1 - 
  12 cb1 sa1 + 36 sb1 - 48 sb2 - 42 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 240 ca1 + 72 ca1 cb1 - 396 cb2 - 141 cb2 cc2 - 80 sa1 - 24 cb1 sa1 - 
  24 sb1 + 132 sb2 + 47 cc2 sb2 + 47 sc2, -80 ca1 + 132 ca3 - 
  24 ca1 cb1 + 47 ca3 cc3 + 240 sa1 + 72 cb1 sa1 - 396 sa3 - 
  141 cc3 sa3 - 24 sb1 + 47 sc3, -80 ca1 + 132 ca3 - 24 ca1 cb1 + 
  47 ca3 cc3 - 80 sa1 - 24 cb1 sa1 + 132 sa3 + 47 cc3 sa3 + 72 sb1 + 
  47 sc3, -1 + ca1^2 + sa1^2, -1 + ca3^2 + sa3^2, -1 + cb1^2 + 
  sb1^2, -1 + cb2^2 + sb2^2, -1 + cc2^2 + sc2^2, -1 + cc3^2 + sc3^2} *)
```

Now we can solve as an explicitly polynomial system and discard solutions we know we don't want.

```
AbsoluteTiming[solns = NSolve[system, vars];]
realsolns = Select[solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]

(* Out[458]= {70.711000, Null}

Out[459]= {{ca1 -> 0.990630862403695, ca3 -> 0.9979298911476929, 
  cb1 -> 0.934822592828836, cb2 -> 0.7084047167567334, 
  cc2 -> -0.8662454504796822, cc3 -> -0.9999646433353357, 
  sa1 -> 0.136566813442575, sa3 -> 0.064311224360259, 
  sb1 -> 0.3551150814680469, sb2 -> -0.7058064588857618, 
  sc2 -> -0.4996186746971847, 
  sc3 -> -0.008408833303751029}, {ca1 -> 0.972091493240758, 
  ca3 -> 0.998009033155138, cb1 -> -0.21452025398996, 
  cb2 -> 0.8166902165390839, cc2 -> -0.7788950631571803, 
  cc3 -> -0.8246152396274358, sa1 -> -0.2346020638556038, 
  sa3 -> 0.0630711585948249, sb1 -> -0.9767195392697885, 
  sb2 -> -0.5770763310610337, sc2 -> 0.6271542722956184, 
  sc3 -> 0.5656940010378115}, {ca1 -> 0.971507343886548, 
  ca3 -> 0.9821460285499906, cb1 -> 0.9547232610884067, 
  cb2 -> 0.9261788653705688, cc2 -> 0.4910652194470647, 
  cc3 -> -0.8573410874746823, sa1 -> -0.2370094527740707, 
  sa3 -> -0.1881201193479485, sb1 -> -0.2974953766665983, 
  sb2 -> 0.3770844875111226, sc2 -> 0.8711228116865195, 
  sc3 -> 0.5147487333197118}, {ca1 -> 0.9934049728071653, 
  ca3 -> 0.9999696133112789, cb1 -> 0.8608241235336918, 
  cb2 -> 0.9946210910361825, cc2 -> -0.9110950988182576, 
  cc3 -> -0.9739805097467558, sa1 -> 0.1146584399772491, 
  sa3 -> -0.007795696710271489, sb1 -> 0.5089025424471438, 
  sb2 -> 0.1035803316990695, sc2 -> -0.4121961898790074, 
  sc3 -> -0.2266317667193753}, {ca1 -> 0.990630862243453, 
  ca3 -> 0.9991361112906542, cb1 -> 0.9348225888440881, 
  cb2 -> 0.7084047175344481, cc2 -> -0.8662454499292845, 
  cc3 -> -0.009747051357440676, sa1 -> 0.1365668118363446, 
  sa3 -> 0.04155756756853254, sb1 -> 0.3551150765172533, 
  sb2 -> -0.7058064571601258, sc2 -> -0.4996186701131406, 
  sc3 -> -0.9999524921381223}, {ca1 -> 0.9934049733388737, 
  ca3 -> 0.9999846585487638, cb1 -> 0.8608241316947258, 
  cb2 -> 0.9946210912529978, cc2 -> -0.9110951047761441, 
  cc3 -> -0.2266528053669567, sa1 -> 0.1146584446193901, 
  sa3 -> -0.005539205115196547, sb1 -> 0.5089025584468246, 
  sb2 -> 0.1035803317166068, sc2 -> -0.4121962042393866, 
  sc3 -> -0.9739756187235958}, {ca1 -> 0.9715073439149983, 
  ca3 -> 0.9938480439189615, cb1 -> 0.954723195368781, 
  cb2 -> 0.9261788594717576, cc2 -> 0.4910651488053675, 
  cc3 -> 0.5056808891042688, sa1 -> -0.2370094528804785, 
  sa3 -> -0.1107522660767406, sb1 -> -0.2974954149639326, 
  sb2 -> 0.3770844348460939, sc2 -> 0.871122798741875, 
  sc3 -> -0.8627206024468279}, {ca1 -> 0.972091493240887, 
  ca3 -> 0.9993117833812833, cb1 -> -0.2145200534910795, 
  cb2 -> 0.8166902361952415, cc2 -> -0.7788948435769054, 
  cc3 -> 0.5647276928243201, sa1 -> -0.23460206466597, 
  sa3 -> 0.03709387881898878, sb1 -> -0.9767194217775088, 
  sb2 -> -0.5770761644367379, sc2 -> 0.6271543154910285, 
  sc3 -> -0.8252773053512772}} *)
```

You can get candidate angles from this by taking inverse trigs, say arccos's of the cosine values.

```
ArcCos[cvars /. realsolns]

(* Out[462]= {{0.1369949224052047, 0.06435562868860302, 
  0.363037167803944, 0.7835609165398749, 2.61843413925789, 
  3.133183507020114}, {0.2368091879519997, 0.06311303912836261, 
  1.786996949192178, 0.6151442423709425, 2.463698385131359, 
  2.54031803280406}, {0.2392864347266495, 0.1892477383549457, 
  0.3020681676620585, 0.3866463759054244, 1.057484182694673, 
  2.600878105372413}, {0.1149111746751269, 0.007795747894100299, 
  0.5339094523934118, 0.1037664493253039, 2.716729378155218, 
  2.912974564098388}, {0.1369949235785647, 0.04156953504571647, 
  0.3630371790249482, 0.783560915437994, 2.618434138156255, 
  1.580543532495388}, {0.1149111700378031, 0.005539222050615004, 
  0.5339094363568763, 0.1037664472320943, 2.716729392609224, 
  1.799435996760292}, {0.239286434606611, 0.110979946027804, 
  0.3020683885717234, 0.3866463915486326, 1.057484263787367, 
  1.040625309080896}, {0.2368091879514502, 0.03710244125552175, 
  1.78699674391434, 0.6151442083093166, 2.463698035009807, 
  0.970693068874044}} *)
```

These could in principle require further adjustment by multiples of `2Pi` but it appears all these actually meet the required ranges from the original formulation. So we might be done at this point.

There is a caveat to how I selected "real" solutions. In general there could be smallish complex parts that should just be smacked with `Chop`. This is more prone to happening in version 10 (I used 9 above), due to introduction of a different default method for NSolve. So you might need to alter the selection criterion.

--- edit ---

I may have had a cut-and-paste or other error yesterday. When I repeated this in version 10 I get the results below. Notice I also use the nondefault `Method` setting for `NSolve`.

```
tpolys = TrigExpand[{F1[a1, b1, b2, c2], F2[a1, b1, b2, c2], 
    F3[a1, b1, b2, c2], G1[a1, b1, a3, c3], G2[a1, b1, a3, c3], 
    G3[a1, b1, a3, c3]}];

subs = {Cos[a_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["c", ToString[a]]], 
   Sin[a_] :> ToExpression[StringJoin["s", ToString[a]]]};

polys = Numerator[Together[tpolys /. subs]];
vars = Variables[polys];
cvars = Cases[vars, ca_ /; StringMatchQ[ToString[ca], "c" ~~ __]];
svars = Map[ToExpression[StringReplacePart[ToString[#], "s", 1]] &, 
   cvars];
extrapolys = cvars^2 + svars^2 - 1;
system = Join[polys, extrapolys]

(* Out[177]= {-123 + 120 ca1 + 36 ca1 cb1 - 48 cb2 - 42 cb2 cc2 - 
  40 sa1 - 12 cb1 sa1 - 12 sb1 + 16 sb2 + 14 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 41 - 40 ca1 - 12 ca1 cb1 + 16 cb2 + 14 cb2 cc2 + 120 sa1 + 
  36 cb1 sa1 - 12 sb1 + 16 sb2 + 14 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 41 - 40 ca1 - 12 ca1 cb1 + 16 cb2 + 14 cb2 cc2 - 40 sa1 - 
  12 cb1 sa1 + 36 sb1 - 48 sb2 - 42 cc2 sb2 + 14 sc2, 
 240 ca1 - 396 ca3 + 72 ca1 cb1 - 141 ca3 cc3 - 80 sa1 - 24 cb1 sa1 + 
  132 sa3 + 47 cc3 sa3 - 24 sb1 + 47 sc3, -80 ca1 + 132 ca3 - 
  24 ca1 cb1 + 47 ca3 cc3 + 240 sa1 + 72 cb1 sa1 - 396 sa3 - 
  141 cc3 sa3 - 24 sb1 + 47 sc3, -80 ca1 + 132 ca3 - 24 ca1 cb1 + 
  47 ca3 cc3 - 80 sa1 - 24 cb1 sa1 + 132 sa3 + 47 cc3 sa3 + 72 sb1 + 
  47 sc3, -1 + ca1^2 + sa1^2, -1 + ca3^2 + sa3^2, -1 + cb1^2 + 
  sb1^2, -1 + cb2^2 + sb2^2, -1 + cc2^2 + sc2^2, -1 + cc3^2 + sc3^2} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 solns = NSolve[system, vars, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"];]
realsolns = Select[solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]

(* Out[178]= {17.763143, Null}

Out[179]= {{ca1 -> 0.979750003005, ca3 -> 0.996336766907, 
  cb1 -> -0.429137780626, cb2 -> 0.0317189516497, 
  cc2 -> -0.866934864031, cc3 -> -0.887281421052, 
  sa1 -> -0.200224702778, sa3 -> 0.0855163545761, 
  sb1 -> -0.903239040968, sb2 -> -0.999496827673, 
  sc2 -> 0.498421449716, 
  sc3 -> 0.461228446452}, {ca1 -> 0.993540741044, 
  ca3 -> 0.999856850531, cb1 -> 0.844669056691, cb2 -> 0.97345748387, 
  cc2 -> -0.913706877747, cc3 -> -0.961917766587, 
  sa1 -> 0.113475970725, sa3 -> -0.0169197646192, 
  sb1 -> 0.535288880379, sb2 -> 0.2288679264, sc2 -> -0.406373894372, 
  sc3 -> -0.273339002747}, {ca1 -> 0.9768581776, ca3 -> 0.90728502041,
   cb1 -> 0.746082752419, cb2 -> 0.683597785102, 
  cc2 -> 0.663822633362, cc3 -> -0.940421761982, 
  sa1 -> -0.213888056756, sa3 -> -0.420516220492, 
  sb1 -> 0.665853231927, sb2 -> 0.72985893691, sc2 -> 0.74789003939, 
  sc3 -> -0.340010160984}, {ca1 -> 0.959065483504, 
  ca3 -> 0.909334697489, cb1 -> -0.631858449557, cb2 -> -0.7184612274,
   cc2 -> 0.75499757274, cc3 -> -0.918342134509, 
  sa1 -> 0.283184389373, sa3 -> 0.416065389022, 
  sb1 -> -0.775083801765, sb2 -> -0.695567009487, 
  sc2 -> -0.655727584595, sc3 -> 0.395787473242}} *)

ArcCos[cvars /. realsolns]

(* Out[180]= {{0.201587262496, 0.0856209299892, 2.01433430099, 
  1.53907205404, 2.61981567378, 2.66221344643}, {0.113720927089, 
  0.0169205723658, 0.564849713432, 0.230914581164, 2.72311067655, 
  2.86473013207}, {0.21555340255, 0.434014217947, 0.728636850982, 
  0.81811557438, 0.844877861826, 2.79466495135}, {0.28711279366, 
  0.429114103112, 2.25474494198, 2.37238385409, 0.715145908928, 
  2.7346674664}} *)
```

Hoping this is an improvement over what I showed earlier.

--- end edit ---

Comment: @ Daniel: Very nice convenient changing of variables, I just wonder whether the "NSolve[system, vars]," you have there, should it be modified to NSolve[system={0,0,0,.....}, vars]? There should be a series of zeros are the RIGHT hand side of equations? Thank you Daniel.

Comment: `NSolve` is forgiving in terms of whether it receives a set of explicit equations vs. a set (`List`) of expressions explicitly set to zero (that is, `{expr1,...,exprn}==0`) vs just a set of expressions. In that last case `NSolve` infers that they are to be set to zero.

Comment: Somehow there are some typos, the correct input should be: TrigExpand[{F1[a1, b1, b2, c2], F2[a1, b1, b2, c2], 
    F3[a1, b1, b2, c2], G1[a1, b1, b2, c2], G2[a1, b1, a3, c3], 
    G3[a1, b1, a3, c3]}]

Comment: And your calculation output seem not to be matched to the input... ? Not sure why.

Comment: I may have made a cut-and-paste mistake somewhere. If I get a chance I'll try to replicate the computation.

Comment: If you run the new-input I edited for you above, I find, at least for my Mathematica 10, it will jump out of the evaluation and turn off the Kernal.

Comment: I later also had that experience, in version 10. I filed a bug report and am even trying to learn a bit more (it's not actually mine) in a debugger. Suffice it to say I believe the crash will be taken seriously. Sorry about that. Aso for getting back v9 behavior, I will suggest in `NSolve` setting `Method->"CompanionMatrix"` and see if matters improve.

Answer (score 1):

I post an answer based on the comment from J.M. using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) and parallel to Daniel Lichtblau set-up.

Pre-set-up:

```
    F1[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] := -(41/4) + Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - 
   Cos[b2] (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);

F2[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] := (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);

F3[a1_, b1_, b2_, c2_] := 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   3 Sin[b1] - (4 + (7 Cos[c2])/2) Sin[b2] + 
   1/16 (-159 + 16 Cos[b2] + 14 Cos[b2] Cos[c2] + 16 Sin[b2] + 
      14 Cos[c2] Sin[b2] + 14 Sin[c2]);

G1[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] := 
  Cos[a1] (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) - Cos[a3] (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) + 
   1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);

G2[a1_, b1_, a3_, 
   c3_] := (10 + 3 Cos[b1]) Sin[a1] - (33/2 + (47 Cos[c3])/8) Sin[
     a3] + 1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);

G3[a1_, b1_, a3_, c3_] := 
  1/4 (50 - 10 Cos[a1] - 3 Cos[a1] Cos[b1] - 10 Sin[a1] - 
      3 Cos[b1] Sin[a1] - 3 Sin[b1]) + 3 Sin[b1] + 
   1/32 (-400 + 132 Cos[a3] + 47 Cos[a3] Cos[c3] + 132 Sin[a3] + 
      47 Cos[c3] Sin[a3] + 47 Sin[c3]);
```

Code:

```
tpolys = TrigExpand[{F1[a1, b1, b2, c2], F2[a1, b1, b2, c2], 
    F3[a1, b1, b2, c2], G1[a1, b1, a3, c3], G2[a1, b1, a3, c3], 
    G3[a1, b1, a3, c3]}];

subs = {Cos[a_] :> (
    1 - ToExpression[StringJoin["t", ToString[a]]]^2)/(
    1 + ToExpression[StringJoin["t", ToString[a]]]^2), 
   Sin[a_] :> (2 *ToExpression[StringJoin["t", ToString[a]]])/(
    1 + ToExpression[StringJoin["t", ToString[a]]]^2)};

polys = Numerator[Together[tpolys /. subs]];

vars = Variables[polys];



NSolve[polys, vars,Reals]
Reduce[polys == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, vars,Reals]
```

However, if you really run the code at the last line, I find, at least for my **Mathematica 10, it will jump out of the evaluation and turn off the Kernal. This can be a bug**, but quotient out this bug problem --- it can be a way to NSolve the problem **if the Mathematica bug is fixed!**

Comment: (Tempted to downvote for use of "kernal"...). I'll try this when I get a chance. Are you saying that the `Reduce[...]` formulation crashes the Mathematica kernel? If so that would be unrelated to the bug we both ran against in version 10 `NSolve`, and it would also warrant further investigation.

Comment: New Update: I get the code work if I tried to modify the method via Method->"EndomorphismMatrix." Namely, try: NSolve[system,vars,Reals,{Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"}]

Comment: How long does it take for that to run? I'm getting no result after several minutes (better than a crash though).